# Calculating the length needed between two bridged circles to produce a given angle / slope

Tags: modeling, mathematics

Calculating the length needed between two bridged circles to produce a given angle / slope

I have two circles which I bridge together.  How can I calculate the length / distance required between the two circles to have the angle / slope be 13 degrees

Example:

I create and bridge 2 circles.

```
1st circle radius 3
2nd circle radius of 1.3
```

**What formula would I need to use to calculate the length / distance required between the two circles to have the angle / slope be **13** degrees?**

[image: img1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the mnemonic 'SOHCAHTOA', you know `tan (theta) = opposite/adjacent` ... 
 so `opposite = adjacent * tan(theta)` =

[image]

so, starting with the top profile, ('opposite' height =  1) .. we know 
 `h = 0.85 * tan (13 degrees)`
 .. but the (Pythonic) entry fields expect angles in radians.

Just a note: The `0.85` comes from `(3.0-1.3) / 2 = 0.85`

So to scale the `1` height (here in Y) to the right length, you could <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> the top figure, followed by typing:

`0.85 * tan(13/360 * tau)`
into the 'Y' field of the scale operator's <kbd>F9</kbd> 'Adjust Last Operation' panel, which yields about `0.196`.

Comment: with a degree in math and 20 years of numerical programming, how have I never seen that mnemonic before?  What are you using for your 3d-cad like annotations?

Comment: @MartyFouts  Ancient English school curriculum, taught by demobbed WWII vets with a Victorian attitude.. :)  Looking back from here, it would have been more useful to take the trig. equivalences approach? 2. The shipped 'Measureit' add-on, which can also give you readable vertex-numbers, etc.

Comment: @MartyFouts  here's a video of it
https://youtu.be/mnnc_EOSYlQ

Comment: @RickT thanks.  I knew about Measureit, I just never realized it would do the angled versions of the end lines, so I didn't recognize it.  YATTR.  (Yet Another Thing To Remember)

Comment: @MartyFouts `janlu`? (Just Another Linux User?)

Comment: @RobinBetts `janud` (Just Another Unix Developer.) you?

Comment: @Marty Just brought up on  `/..?n[ui]x/gm/`, so I like the way they think. And they're not constantly dumping stuff on **my** machine, ffs, or nagging me,  trying to corner me in to their monopolized ecosystems.

Comment: @RickT Thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm no good at trigonometry, so I'll just use [this online calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1273849674).
It also gives you the right formula if you wanna try by hand.

- *Base* is the difference between radius values (3 - 1.3 = 1.7)
- *Angle* is 13 degrees

So the *Height* required is **0.392** units.

[image]

Comment: Slick! But the link is to the gif, not the calculator, and I can't seem to find the right one to pop in an edit for you :)

Comment: thanks for the heads up, works now :)

Comment: .. and it should be 0.85, not 1.7 .. you forgot to cut your cone in half  :) .. (what a PITA I am ...)

Comment: Hey Robin, thanks for checking, I'm no math wiz :D. Though the numbers work out fine when i actually model it... [confused]

Comment: I might be up the creek myself */* ... justification in my A.